# Excel adds an extra row when transferring T SQL server results from a ntext column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

The `QS` column in my database is of type `ntext`. Why when I transfer the following query results to Excel 2010, I get extra rows.

Here is my query:

```
select qn, replace(ltrim(rtrim(cast(qs as nvarchar(max)))),'  ',' ')
from qry
where qn like ('Credit Deficient %')
```

This is how it looks like in SQL Server 2012 query result window:

```
LIST STU SC GR LN FN CC BY SC IF CC < 70  AND GR = 10 AND SC < 11
```

Excel, however, splits across two rows as:

```
 LIST STU SC GR LN FN CC BY SC IF CC < 70  AND GR
```

and:

```
 = 10 AND SC < 11
```

Please advise how to update my output into a single row in Excel.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Just an idea...is it possible that there are actually hidden newline characters in between GR and =? Just try manually removing the space between GR and =, and adding the space again and then try and see if you still get the same results.

Comment: It is possible you could have line feed or carriage return in your data though you can't see it in SSMS when results are to grid. One thing you could do is in SSMS is before you run you query press CTRL + T while in the query window. This will change your results to text in that query window. Then run your query and you'll see the results in text format which will reveal any carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will `replace` a line feed (char(10)) and carriage returns (char(13)) with a space.

```
select qn, replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(cast(qs as nvarchar(max)))),'  ',' '), char(13), ' '), char(10), ' ')
from qry
where qn like ('Credit Deficient %')
```